# Scrapy Python spider: Storing results in Latin-1, not in unicode

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

Currently my spider fetches results as needed but encodes them in unicode (UTF-8, I believe). When I save these results to a csv, I have a ton of cleaning to do as a result, with all the [u' & other characters that Scrapy inserts.

How exactly would I store the results as Latin characters, & not unicode. Where exactly would I need to make the change?

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: Your problem isn't unicode, it's that whatever program you're using to open it expects latin-1. It should have an option when you open it to use UTF-8 as the character encoding.

Comment: You can also use unicode_to_str function from from scrapy.utils.python , set the encoding as 'latin-1' and errors as 'ignore'

Answer (score 4):

The item_extracted is of type unicode. You can either encode it to latin where it's extracted (in the parse function) or in an [item pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example) or [output processor](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors)

Easiest way is to add this line to your parse function

```
item_to_be_stored = item_extracted.encode('latin-1','ignore')
```

Or you could define a function in your item class.

```
from scrapy.utils.python import unicode_to_str

def u_to_str(text):
    unicode_to_str(text,'latin-1','ignore')

class YourItem(Item):
    name = Field(output_processor=u_to_str())
```

Comment: thanks @buffer. I think it makes sense to have this in the item pipeline. Not sure exactly where your code should go. My current item pipeline goes like this: class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

Comment: Does the unicode_to_str() need an argument? I am  getting error saying at least 1 argument is needed; I tried unicode_to_str('latin-1', 'ignore'), but no luck, I continue to get the data wrapped in [u'. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, here's the function definition unicode_to_str(text, encoding=None, errors='strict'). You are using it incorrectly, hence the error. You can add a wrapper to this function to hardcode the encoding & errors parameter. The one arg function can be passed as the output_processor. See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is what you say it is, the solution is as simple as casting to a string.

```
>>> a = u'spam and eggs'
>>> a
u'spam and eggs'
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> b = str(a)
>>> b
'spam and eggs'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
```

EDIT:
Knowing that an exception could occur it might be a good idea to wrap this in a try and except

```
try:
    str(a)
except UnicodeError:
    print "Skipping string %s" % a
```

Comment: If the string contains non-ASCII characters, this will raise `UnicodeEncodeError`.